# Stop opening a result on a google search page in new tab Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-search

When I do a search in Google Chrome, the Google.com website comes up with all of my search results. Then, I go to click on a search result. It opens the search result in a new tab, instead of in the same tab.

How do I get

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Google search results should open in the same tab for all browsers. Check your [Google Search Settings](http://www.google.com/preferences) and make sure that `Open each selected result in a new browser window` is **not** enabled.

[image: screen shot]